# Send a grid data to the server Exjts4

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, extjs4

As do to send all the data in a grid in extjs to the server?

My Store

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {            
            autoDestroy: true,
            autoLoad: true,
            fields: ['property', 'value']
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',                
                url: '...',                
                reader: {
                    type: 'json'                                        
                },
                writer: {
                    url: '...',                
                }
            },
            sorters: [{
                property: 'common',
                direction:'ASC'
            }]
        });
```

I have a grid that uses my store.

I have tried to this but it doesn't work

```
mygrid.getStore().add(mygrid.getStore().getRange(0,2));
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined your store as a variable 'store'. So you would just need to call `store.save()`. The save function will use the url defined by your store.proxy to post the data back to the database.

I noticed that you are putting a `url` config inside of your `proxy.writer`, which doesn't have a url config option. `proxy.writer` is used to translate the json, xml, etc before it gets to the proxy.

If you want to use different backend controllers for CRUD operations you could specify these in the `api` config of the proxy you are using (Ext.data.proxy.Ajax). Take a look at the `api` config item on [**this**](http://lthe.fr/ext4/docs/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.html) page.